# Installing command line tools for Open Data Cube?

Tags: installation, open-data-cube

I am trying to setup my own Open Data Cube environment, I did installed Postgres and datacube python libraries, but in order to initialise the database schema the following command is suggested:

```
  datacube -v system init
```

I have not being able to find instructions to install command line tools for ODC? Where can I find them?

I have my Linux machine and executed the following commands to install opendatacube Python API:

- conda config --add channels conda-forge
- conda create --name cubeenv python=3.6 datacube
- source activate cubeenv
- activate cubeenv
- conda install jupyter matplotlib scipy

Also I executed the following commands to install postgres and start it:

- sudo yum install postgresql12
- sudo yum install postgresql12-contrib
- /usr/pgsql-12/bin/initdb

I think I have not executed any steps to install command line toos, I am following this link:

https://opendatacube.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ops/install.html

followed by database setup steps.

In these database setup steps, the last one is to initialise database schema, and I was planning to execute it using bash window.

Comment: The command line tools are installed, but your system doesn't know where they are. Please edit your question and specify how you installed `datacube` and how you are trying to run the command.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [section "Manual installation (Fallback)"](https://datacube-core.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ops/windows.html#datacube-installation) in the docs. There is nothing wrong with your conda environment...keep it. For some reason your system does not recognize the command. Activate your conda environment and `git pull` a copy of the [datacube-core](https://github.com/opendatacube/datacube-core) source code repository.

`cd` into the datacube-core directory and manually install it typing

```
python setup.py install
```

The `datacube` command should be available then.

Comment: This is a good answer, but it'll install a 'dirty' version of the ODC. You can just PIP install it once your Conda install is working. https://pypi.org/project/datacube/